Suppose that $f(x)\leq g(x)\,\, \forall x$, prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\leq \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$
Suppose that $f(x)\leq g(x)\,\, \forall x$, prove that $\lim_{x 
\to a} f(x) \leq  \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$.
So to start off, assuming both limits exist at $x=a$.
let the $\varepsilon$ for $f(x)$ be $\varepsilon_1$ and that for $g(x)$ be $\varepsilon_2$
Let the limit for $f(x)=L_1$ and for $g(x)=L_2$
let $max(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2) = \varepsilon_o$
so we then have $ L_1 -\varepsilon_o \leq f(x) \leq L_1-\varepsilon_o$
and
$ L_2 -\varepsilon_o \leq g(x) \leq L_2-\varepsilon_o$
I did think of subtracting the two equations, not sure of how to proceed from there.
I'm also not sure if I should take the max or min.
Thanks

The question does not match the title. $<$ is not the same as $\le $.

corrected  the question

The answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1270897/1264525 to more or less the same question should explain what you need.

https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%30%5Cto%20a%7D%20f(x)%20%5Cleq%20%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%20a%7D%20g(x)%24&p=1
